# Remove Last Modified and Size From mod_autoindex

Tags: html, css, apache, mod-autoindex

I was working on a file storage page for my website, and I figured out how to do a lot of things so it using mod_autoindex for my apache server, and now I want to remove the Last Modified and Size field from the table.

If that could be done some way or another it would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found out that by injecting JS into the header/footer it would be easy to remove.

Answer (score 0):

This can actually be done using only Apache directives. I'm *very* late answering this question, but I'm leaving this for future reference. This works for Apache v2.0+.

The required directives are:

```
<IfModule mod_autoindex.c>
  IndexOptions FancyIndexing
  IndexOptions SuppressLastModified
  IndexOptions SuppressSize
</IfModule>
```

The most convenient location for these directives is likely to be the .htaccess file in the directory you wish to style.

Note: The `FancyIndexing` option is **required** to enable the two `Suppress` options.  They won't work without it.

[Official Apache IndexOptions Documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/mod/mod_autoindex.html#IndexOptions)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this in the httpd.conf to remove the last modified header in the  response.

Header unset Last-Modified